# Mi HTML no reconoce el CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este HTML y este CSS pero cuando actualizo el navegador, no hay ningún cambio

```css
<style>


 #a {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
 }
  
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="es">  
    <head>  
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>  
        <title>Proyecto</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="123.css">
    </head>  
    <body>  
      <header> 
        <li id="a">Hola</li>
      </header>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si tienes un archivo `.css` no tienes que indicar las etiquetas `<style>`. Son etiquetas `html`.

```css
 #a {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<html lang="es">  
    <head>  
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>  
        <title>Proyecto</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="123.css">
    </head>  
    <body>  
      <header> 
        <li id="a">Hola</li>
      </header>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Lo curioso es que otros archivos css, los abro con la etiqueta <style> y sí me detecta los cambios sin ningún problema. Pero bueno, en este caso se solucionó quitándola.